# Trying different functions

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

in the first function, I'm making the job column lowercase and then searching through but it's not finding any data. Why? Thanks. Just FYI since you don't have the database, all records in the JOB column are uppercase (that's why isn't returning anything), but that's also why I'm making it lowercase first.

In the second function, I'm trying to concat only ename with specific criteria --anything that has an r in the ENAME column (there are multiple records with the r in it), but isn't working (no data found), why? How do I get it done? Thanks.

```
SELECT LOWER(JOB) FROM EMP
WHERE JOB = LOWER('MANAGER');
```

```
SELECT CONCAT('My name is ',ename)
FROM EMP
WHERE ENAME LIKE '%r%';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested both of your SQL statements and they work fine for me. Are you sure the records are in db? Are you sure the names of the rows are correct?

EDIT :  OK, so the name of column is in lower case but in your WHERE its in uppercase. Thats all :)

Comment: thanks! Yes, here is the result of the query for the first one without the where clause: LOWER(JOB)
president
manager
manager
manager
analyst
analyst
clerk
salesman
salesman
salesman
salesman
clerk
clerk
clerk

Comment: I found the problem with my second query (I'm new so please bear with me). My 'r' was lowercase and all records are in uppercase.

Comment: @Ruben It's ok. Ok, try this "SELECT LOWER(JOB) FROM EMP
WHERE LOWER(JOB) = LOWER('MANAGER');" it should work. I'll provide explanation in my answer

Comment: @Ruben, Haha thank you ^^ Glad to help. Since this answer was helpful, can you please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)?

Comment: I think I just did, can you please double check? Thanks!

Comment: @Ruben, oh yeah you did :) Thanks a lot ^^.

Comment: what's the explanation for the answer? :)

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. It's pretty simple actually. The name of the column in the where clause was in lower case. Thats why I added that "WHERE LOWER(JOB)" bit. Simply adding "WHERE job" could've solved the problem easily. Sorry if my solution confused you.